# How to insert multiple days into a calendar intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I'm trying to set up an intent to prepopulate an event in the calendar app with the days the user selects. Here is the intent:

```
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
                intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
                intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=" + duration );
                intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,name + " Reminder" );
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

"Duration" Can contain the names of the days in the following format."Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc".The problem is from what I've seen so far BYDAY is in the formation of MO, TU, WE, etc... Is there anyway for me to include the full name of the days in the calendar intent or must put the days of the week in the terms of MO, TU, WE, etc... If that is not the case is there anyway to do that since duration can contain the full names of the days of the week separate by commas?

I figured out how to change the formation of the string to two characters but it is only for one word. For example if the user just selects Monday I'm able to change it to Mo using the following code:

```
  int durationColumnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex    (PrescriptionContract.PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_FREQUENCY_DURATION);
                String duration1 = mCursor.getString(durationColumnIndex);
                if (duration1.length()>=2){
                    duration1 = duration1.substring(0,2);
```

However if the user selects multiple dates duration1 becomes: "Monday Wednesday Sunday" for example. Is there a way to change this string to just Mo,We,Su so it can be sent in an calendar intent?

Comment: [refer this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563608/2794507)

Comment: Thanks but I’m still confused as to how this will allow me to take what is in my variable, say “Monday, Wednesday, Sunday” and covert that to language it can be sent as an intent that allows an event to occur weekly on those days.