# How to set reminder for partcular date and time in devices above 6.0

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Actually I got the code using Alarm manager, but there was one issue, for that we need to open our app daily once in case of phone switched 0ff or restart. Then only that alarm/reminder gets triggered. Any other solution?

Comment: [refer this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563608/2794507) i hope it will help you

Comment: it's fine, Thnaks for replying but I want to generate local notification when the reminder time comes up.Any idea?

Comment: no idea about that but you have get solution please let me know otherwise post your ans. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, fine I will post my ans If I got one.

Comment: You need to implement a BroadcastReceiver that is called on device boot to recreate your alarm(s) (which you'll have to have safely stored somewhere, presumably database or preference).

Comment: That I did, for that also we need to open our app once in a day for devices over 6.0, then only that receiver gets called while device rebooting time and sets the alarm