# Android add an event silently to the Google calendar

Tags: android, kotlin, google-calendar-api

I been browsing around for an answer for my question, but all I find are old solutions. I have added the event using an uri but the default sync has overwritten my events :(. Then I tried to use the calendar API 3 without any luck. As the title says, how can I insert an event into the calendar silently?

```
val calendarQuickStart = CalendarQuickStart(getApplicationContext())
Thread({
    val service = Calendar.Builder(NetHttpTransport(), JsonFactory, calendarQuickStart.getCredentials(NetHttpTransport())).build()

    var event = Event()
            .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
            .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
            .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.")

    val startDateTime = DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00")
    val start = EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
    event.start = start

    val endDateTime = DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00")
    val end = EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
    event.end = end

    val recurrence = "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"
    event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence))

    val attendees = EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com")
    event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees))

    val reminderOverrides = (EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60))
    val reminders = Event.Reminders()
            .setUseDefault(false)
            .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides))
    event.reminders = reminders

    val calendarId = "primary"
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute()
    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.htmlLink)

}).start()
```

Here is my implementation of the calendar API 3. But if you have a better suggestion for adding a event that can sync with your calendar. It feels kinda overkill using a libary just to add a event into the calendar.

Comment: It would help if you could post your implementation. Otherwise its hard to find a solution.

Comment: [refer this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563608/2794507) i hope it will help you!.

Comment: That's the uri way I talked about briefly. This way works until the sync comes are restores everything.